# How do I set the time?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, time

System Settings -> Date and Time. This dialog allows to set time zone and date, but doesn't allow to set the time. How can I change the time?

[image]

Comment: Are you using standard Ubuntu, or GNOME Classic, or something else? Your screen-shot does not match the standard Ubuntu 12.04 date & time settings.

Comment: And if you click the little up and down arrows above and bellow the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have 12.10 (gnome session fallback) and my screen looks exactly like yours. With the network time slider to off the **little tick marks above and below the numbers** - when clicked - will adjust the time. Also the time zone can be selected by changing the region and city.

Comment: Wow, I see those tiny ticks now as well. Without having seen the rest of the UI, I'd call them a bug in the UI design. OTOH I guess someone frantically clicking around will eventually find them. Do they go away and reappear when you switch "Network time" on and off? That would be a mitigating factor ...

Comment: The ticks are rendered functionless when network time is enabled. Did you try to set your location?

Answer (score 4):

You can manually set the time by first selecting "Manually" instead of "Automatically from the Internet".

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I don't see such commands in the dialog. Can you give some details?

Comment: Are you sure you are on 12.04?

Comment: The question is edited. Yes, this is 12.04 32 bit.

Comment: @AlexFarber Have you tried resizing the window? Can you click the time (the large 15:23)?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Network Time, then it can be adjusted manually.

Comment: Network time is off, but I still don't see how can I change the time.

Comment: There are little arrows above & below the numbers, (at least in GNOME fallback session.)

Comment: The question is edited.